# ASP.NET Forms Authentication, allowing a user to access specific pages only with username

Tags: c#, asp.net

i AM WORKING WITH ASP.NET 4.5 web forms:
I need users to be able to Reset their Password via email *(still working on that)*, ***Security Question/Answer*** and using the ***Forget Password method***.

The problem I have is that, in-order to use the Reset/Change password Method, I need to turn the Security Question/Answer to false. So I created a work around by creating a table which stores the Security Question and Answer.

When the user answers correctly, in addition to entering an ***ID Number***, they are landed on the Reset Password page. It all works great, they can reset password and log in.

***My problem:***
I need the reset password page to not be public, is there a way I can utilize the ***Username***, which I can get from the DB when the user answers correctly, to give access to the Reset Page?

Currently anyone can get to this URL. I was also thinking about ***Enable/Disable*** controls on the same page rather than a URL.

Thanks for reading my long story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use a Guid as a reset-credentials-token; save it some where in the database (some table) and then use the Guid as a query string parameter to the Reset-Password-page? In the Reset-Pswd page, check if the token in the query string is valid. If it is not, tell the user, it's a bad request or something. Let me know, if it's unclear.

In your Login form, use this in your forgot_pswd Click event handler.

```
var resetToken = Guid.NewGuid();

//Code to insert into a table on the db..
//Have a table something like:
//ResetCredentialsToken(UserId int, Token nvarchar(256), IsExpired int)

YourDAL.InsertPwdToken(userId, resetToken, 0);

Response.Redirect("ResetPswd.aspx?Guid=" + resetToken.ToString());
```

In the ResetPswd.aspx page, check if the token is a valid one.. in Page_Load

```
if (!YourDAL.IsValidToken(userId, resetToken))
   showSomething();
```

Comment: Actually that is a great idea. I feel a little less smart. I was planning on it as part of the email reset link. The truth is I do not know how to do it. But I'll get it going in no time. I guess I am just confused about getting the link with the GUID.

If you want to give me a jump start, that would be great otherwise I still appreciate the answer. I need to do this for the email, anyway.

Comment: Happens. We tend to get lost in out own thoughts pal. I edited the answer now. I don't know what you've got there, it could be VB.NET or C#.. You may have an OLEDB Data access layer, an ADO.NET DAL. I just gave a rough idea in the pseudo code. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example: I am Using SQL Server 2012 and C#/ASP.NET 4.5.
So do I first create this token when the user Creates an account? Or do I perform the above when the user clicks the forgot password button/click event?

Comment: Create it when he/she correctly answers the secret question. Then send the user, an email containing the hyperlink to reset his/her password.. That hyperlink could be "http://yoursite/pwdToken=" + guid

Comment: Thank you VanKat. This is quite a great start for me. Have a great day!